# processing image outside callback

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to process image outside callback. Its a Harris detector using opencv but I am running into **segmentation fault** error.

my code is as follows;

```
namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;
class harris_node
{
  protected:
  //   image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
image_transport::Subscriber sub_;
image_transport::Publisher pub_;
ros::NodeHandle nh_;
ros::NodeHandle nhPrivate_;

sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr imageIn_;
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr image_in;   //pointer to input image
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr image_out;  //for ros msg conversion 
cv::Mat cvImage_in;       //for processing, input at each step
cv::Mat cvImage_out;      //for processing, output at each step
int thresh;
int max_thresh;
int blockSize;
int apertureSize;
double k;


 public:
 harris_node(ros::NodeHandle& nh, ros::NodeHandle& nhPrivate):nh_(nh), nhPrivate_(nhPrivate), thresh(200), max_thresh(255), blockSize(2), apertureSize(3), k(0.04)
 {
    image_transport::ImageTransport it_(nh_);
    sub_ = it_.subscribe("front_cam/camera/image", 100, &harris_node::imageCb, this);
    pub_=it_.advertise("front_cam/camera/image_processed", 1);
 }
  
 void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& image)
 {  
    
    try                         
    {
        imageIn_ = image;        
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
        ROS_ERROR("Conversion error: %s", e.what());
        return;
    }
 }
  
 void harris_detector()
 {
    image_in = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(imageIn_, enc::BGR8);
    cvImage_in = image_in->image;       
    cvtColor(cvImage_in, cvImage_out, CV_8UC1); 
    cvImage_in = cvImage_out;
    cornerHarris(cvImage_in, cvImage_out, blockSize, apertureSize, k, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);    //Harris detector
    cvImage_in = cvImage_out;
    normalize(cvImage_in, cvImage_out, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_32FC1, cv::Mat());       //normalize
    cvImage_in = cvImage_out;
    convertScaleAbs (cvImage_in, cvImage_out); //scaled


    //Drawing circles around corner

    for(int j=0; j<cvImage_out.rows ; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<cvImage_out.cols; i++)
        {
            if((int) cvImage_out.at<float>(j,i) > thresh)
            {
                circle(cvImage_out, cv::Point(j,i),5,cv::Scalar(0),2,8,0);
            }
        }
    
    }
 }
 

 void spin()
 {
    ros::Rate rate(30);
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
 }
 
 virtual void spinOnce()
 {
    harris_detector();
    spin();
 }
 };

 class harris_node_with_gui:public harris_node
 {
public:
harris_node_with_gui(ros::NodeHandle& nh, ros::NodeHandle& nhPrivate):   harris_node(nh, nhPrivate){}
void spinOnce()
{
    harris_node::spinOnce();
    cv::imshow("inputImage", cvImage_in);
    cv::imshow("Corners", cvImage_out); 
}
   };




 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
 ros::init(argc, argv, "image_processor"); 
 ros::NodeHandle nh;
 ros::NodeHandle nhPrivate("~");
 
 harris_node* node = 0;
 node = new harris_node_with_gui (nh, nhPrivate);
 node->spinOnce();
 }
```

gdb debugging shows
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

on backtrace I get:

```
#0  0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb74b81df in raise () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb74bb825 in abort () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb74b1085 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0xb74b1137 in __assert_fail () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0xb7f74555 in    cv_bridge::toCvCopy(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, std::string const&) ()
 from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcv_bridge.so
#6  0x080532bb in harris_node::harris_detector() ()
#7  0x0805372f in harris_node::spinOnce() ()
#8  0x08053778 in harris_node_with_gui::spinOnce() ()
#9  0x080536e1 in harris_node::spin() ()
#10 0x08050f2a in main ()
```

Any help is appreciated..

---

### Edited

After I swap i and j the backtrace output is still the same but I get another error:

```
image_processing: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:412:    boost::shared_ptr<T>::reference boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = const    sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >, boost::shared_ptr<T>::reference = const   sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

So I think I have initialized the pointers in the class to NULL value and this has created the problem. Any suggestion how can I rectify this????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90091/processing-image-outside-callback/) by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-12**:
Please check where the segfault happens with gdb's back trace.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2016-03-21**:
did you ever resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would assume your error lies here

```
if((int) cvImage_out.at<float>(j,i) > thresh)
{
  circle(cvImage_out, cv::Point(i,j),5,cv::Scalar(0),2,8,0);
}
```

I did not read the full code but a quick look at it lets me guess that you access the image outside its boundaries. It looks like you need to swap i and j

Edit:
Have a look at http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages
for the right way to transform sensor_msgs::image to cvimage
It looks like you just assign a const ptr from the message to a const ptr from a cvimage. This is most certainly not correct. Try something like this:

```
cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);
```

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on 2013-10-12**:
Thanks I did the correction..but no solutions yet.

**Comment by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on 2013-10-12**:
I did the following where imageIn_ is ImageConstPtr:
image_in = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(imageIn_, enc::BGR8);

Actually I followed the same tutorial.